# blazor wasm using Cryptography.Algorithms Error

Tags: cryptography, blazor-webassembly

```
   Unhandled exception rendering component: System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms is not supported on this platform.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create()
   at AutoTradingWebAppV2.Helper.Crypto.Encryptstring(String text, String keyString) in D:\Web\AutoTradingApp-BWASM\AutoTradingWebAppV2\Helper\Crypto.cs:line 12
   at AutoTradingWebAppV2.Handler.CustomUpbitAuthHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Web\AutoTradingApp-BWASM\AutoTradingWebAppV2\Handler\CustomUpbitAuthHandler.cs:line 31
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<>n__0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[DTOs.AccountDTO, DTOs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at Services.UpbitService.GetAccounts() in D:\Web\AutoTradingApp-BWASM\Services\UpbitService.cs:line 31
   at AppViewModels.UpbitTradingViewModel.GetAccounts() in D:\Web\AutoTradingApp-BWASM\AppViewModels\UpbitTradingViewModel.cs:line 156
   at AutoTradingWebAppV2.Pages.TradingInfoBoard.TryConnectToWebsocket() in D:\Web\AutoTradingApp-BWASM\AutoTradingWebAppV2\Pages\TradingInfoBoard.razor.cs:line 48
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/cryptography-apis-not-supported-on-blazor-webassembly

then how to create JWT at blazor ? or use AES?

how to fix it or when they update blazor?

```
            var jwtToken = JwtBuilder.Create()
                                     .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
                                     .WithSecret(SecretKey)
                                     .AddClaim("access_key",AccessKey)
                                     .AddClaim("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                                     .Encode();
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
```

I Added this code to httpclient handler, but can not use this code on blazor...

+

here is the open API sampleCode. I have to create JWT Token at Client and send request to api

C# CODE.

```
public class OpenAPISample {
    public static void Main() {
        var payload = new JwtPayload
        {
            { "access_key", "Access Key" },
            { "nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            { "query_hash", queryHash },
            { "query_hash_alg", "SHA512" }
        };

        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Secret Key");
        var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes);
        var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, "HS256");
        var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);
        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(secToken);
        var authorizationToken = "Bearer " + jwtToken;
    }
}
```

JAVA Example CODE (there is no C# CODE in web site)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accessKey = System.getenv("OPEN_API_ACCESS_KEY");
        String secretKey = System.getenv("OPEN_API_SECRET_KEY");
        String serverUrl = System.getenv("OPEN_API_SERVER_URL");

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);
        String jwtToken = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("access_key", accessKey)
                .withClaim("nonce", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);

        String authenticationToken = "Bearer " + jwtToken;

        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serverUrl + "/v1/accounts");
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", authenticationToken);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating the token in the client app? I fail to see why you would desire to that in the first place?

Comment: The sample java code is for a server / desktop app.  You can't put this in a SPA without making your secretKey public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create JWT at blazor ?

A JWT is created on the Server. And consumed by a Client app.

The APIs are unsupported for technical reasons but you shouldn't want to use them on a Client.  Your client is not able to hide any credentials, it would only give false security.

That holds for AES as well. You can't hide the key.

---

> they only give me accesskey and secret key and ask me make jwt

You should do this on your own Server. Your SPA client calls your Server that calls the  Open API server.

Make sure the secret key never ends up in the SPA client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
then how to use Open API from other server? I have to call api from other server. for request I have to set request.Headers.Authorization

Comment: And how does that "other server" do authentication?  Why would it accept a JWT that you created?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
then how to use Open API on other server that requre jwt(they only gived me accesskey and secret key and ask me make jwt and send it to request.header.authorization)? I have to call api from other server. for request, I have to create jwt and set it  in request.Headers.Authorization

Comment: I Edited the qeustion.